# JOIN WHERE and add calculated column

Tags: mysql

Looking for the help. I try to run a code in this order JOIN, WHERE and and GRP number (on the results of my query).

I have two tables test and text:

```
create table test (
    code varchar(10) primary key,
    num int(10) not null,
    name varchar(10) not null,
    surname varchar(10) not null);

insert into test values (1,09,'Tom', 'Smith');
insert into test values (2,09,'Adam','Blake');
insert into test values (3,15,'John','Smith');
insert into test values (4,15,'Adam','XYZ');
insert into test values (5,43,'John','Abc');
insert into test values (6,99,'Adam','Abc');
insert into test values (7,99,'John','Abc');
insert into test values (8,15,'Adam','XYZ');
insert into test values (9,43,'John','Abc');
insert into test values (10,99,'Adam','Abc');
insert into test values (11,99,'John','Abc');
insert into test values (12,1,'A','A');
insert into test values (13,1,'J','A');
```

and table text:

```
create table text (
    code varchar(10) primary key,
    codeFK varchar(10) not null,
    state varchar(10));

insert into text values (1,2,'O');
insert into text values (2,2,'O');
insert into text values (3,2,'O');
insert into text values (4,2,'C');
insert into text values (5,3,'O');
insert into text values (6,3,'O');
insert into text values (7,3,'O');
insert into text values (8,2,'O');
insert into text values (9,2,'C');
insert into text values (10,2,'O');
insert into text values (11,2,'C');
insert into text values (12,1,'C');
insert into text values (13,12,'C');
insert into text values (14,13,'C');
```

I join them and try to add coulm group as per below code:

JOIN - it works

```
SELECT num FROM test
LEFT JOIN text ON test.code = text.codeFK
WHERE state = 'O' 

ORDER BY test.num DESC;
```

GRP calculation on its on

```
select t.*,
       (select count(distinct t2.num)
        from test t2
        where t2.num <= t.num
       ) as grp
from test t ORDER BY GRP;
```

But my question is how to get GRP column with above join query? So, the grp column will be calculated only on the results based on WHERE statement and not the whole table test.

I tried below but it gives me an error:

```
SELECT num FROM test
LEFT JOIN text ON test.code = text.codeFK
WHERE state = 'O' 

AND test.num IN (select t.num,
       (select count(distinct t2.num)
        from test t2
        where t2.num <= t.num
       ) as grp from test t)

ORDER BY test.num DESC;
```

Desired results:

[image]

Comment: the image of the desired results is not causing any harm. We can plainly see what the OP is trying to achieve  from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select test.num, tt.cnt from test 
join text on test.code = text.codefk
join (
    select t1.num, count(*) cnt from (
        select distinct num
        from test ts1 
    join text tx1 on ts1.code = tx1.codefk
    where tx1.state = 'O'
) t1 join (
    select distinct num
    from test ts2
        join text tx2 on ts2.code = tx2.codefk
        where tx2.state = 'O'
    ) t2 on t1.num <= t2.num
    group by t1.num
) tt on test.num = tt.num
where text.state = 'O'
```

Another way, more efficient:

```
select @lagNum := 0, @cnt := 0;
select num, cnt from (
    select case when num <> @lagNum then @cnt := @cnt + 1 end, @cnt cnt, @lagNum := num, num
    from (
        select (select num from test where code = t.codefk) num
        from text t
        where state = 'O'
    ) a order by num
) a
```

Comment: WOW! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ Michal Turczyn. Dzieki jeszcze raz :)

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:** This should point you in the correct direction. Instead of that second query in the `AND` it should be what youre selecting

heres my fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2fe48b/36

```
select t.num,
   (select count(distinct t2.num) - 1
    from test t2
    where t2.num <= t.num
   ) as grp
from test t
LEFT JOIN text ON t.code = text.codeFK
WHERE text.state = 'O' 
ORDER BY t.num DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks however it returns incorrect results. I bet it cannot give the correct results because SQL parsers read the WHERE clause before they read the SELECT expressions. I try having but it does not work either.`select t.num, t.name,
       (select count(distinct t2.num)
        from test t2
        where t2.num <= t.num
       ) as grp
from test t
LEFT JOIN text ON t.code = text.codeFK
GROUP BY t.num, t.name,grp,text.state 
HAVING text.state = 'O' `

Comment: @Kalenji I updated it, I think I see what youre going for now with that grp column